# Copy constructor not used during pass by value in C++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, return-value, copy-constructor

```
class A {
    int x;
public:
    A() { cout << "\t A() \n"; }
    A(int _x): x(_x) { cout << "\t A(int) \n"; }
    A(const A& other): x(other.x) { cout << "\t A(const A&) \n"; }
    A(A&& other): x(std::move(other.x)) { cout << "\t A(A&&) \n"; }
    A& operator=(const A& other) { x = other.x; cout << "\t operator=() \n"; return *this; }
};

void func_1(A obj) {
    cout << "func_1\n";
}

A func_7(const A& obj) {
    cout << "func_7\n";
    return obj;
}

int main() {

    A obj_1;                        // stdout: "A()"                    [OK]
    A obj_2 = 10;                   // stdout: "A(int)"                 [OK]
    A obj_3 = obj_2;                // stdout: "A(const A&)"            [OK]
    A obj_4 = std::move(obj_3);     // stdout: "A(A&&)"                 [OK]
    obj_4 = obj_2;                  // stdout: "operator=()"            [OK]

    func_1(obj_1);                  // stdout: "A(const A&) \n func_1"  [OK]
    func_1(A(5));                   // stdout: "A(int) \n func_1"       [!?] Copy constructor?
    func_1(5);                      // stdout: "A(int) \n func_1"       [!?] Copy constructor?
    A obj_7 = func_7(obj_2);        // stdout: "func_7 \n A(const A&)"  [!?] Copy constructor?

    return 0;
}
```

For `func_1(A(5));`, I expected the output to be `A(int) \n A(const A&) \n func_1` because we are passing `A(5)` by value so the passed object should be copied to the parameter. Similarly for `func_1(5);`.

For `A obj_7 = func_7(obj_2);`, I expected the output to be `func_7 \n A(const A&) \n A(const A&)` because we are returning an object so that object should be copied on the stack first and then the copy constructor will be used to declare `obj_7` using the returned object.

Am I missing something here? I am aware of the return value optimization, but I don't think that will apply in both the functions that we have here.

Comment: I assume that your compiler is smart enough to optimize away the explicit call to `A(5)` in that second line, or much rather the copy (since its a temporary anyway). Meaning it's the same as `passing 5 directly`.

Comment: Temporaries can be elided.   If temporaries are elided, calls of copy constructor to copy said temporary and destructor to destroy it are avoided.       Elision is mostly optional on older C++ standards, but permitted.   In more recent standards (from C++17 on) elision is mandatory in several cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For func_1(A(5));, I expected the output to be A(int) \n A(const A&) \n func_1 because we are passing A(5) by value so the passed object should be copied to the parameter.

You expected wrongly. `A(5)` is a prvalue of the same type, so the temporary object will not be materialised, and its initialiser is instead used to initialise the parameter that would have been initialised by the non-materialised temporary.

> Similarly for func_1(5);.

The class has an implicit converting constructor that accepts an integer. You pass an integer; the converting constructor is used to initialise the parameter.

> For A obj_7 = func_7(obj_2);, I expected the output to be func_7 \n A(const A&) \n A(const A&) because we are returning an object so that object should be copied on the stack first and then the copy constructor will be used to declare obj_7 using the returned object.

The reason for this is similar as the first case. The function call is a prvalue.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `func_1(A(5));`, the *copy ctor* won't be called since `A(5)` is an **rvalue** (aka a temporary). the *copy ctor* is only called when the value on the right-hand side is an **lvalue** (aka a value with a dedicated memory location).

And in the case of `A obj_7 = func_7(obj_2);`, the *copy ctor* will only be invoked once for constructing `obj_7`. It won't be called when you pass `obj_2` as an **lvalue reference** to `func_7`. The parameter of `func_7` is a reference. Not a new object. So no call to *copy ctor* required